# No 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource With Resource Server in Spring Boot

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have to call an API with the access token from the browser which is protected by Resource Server with spring boot `2.4.6`

**GET API** - `http://127.0.0.1:9090/api/user/benz@gmail.com`

When I call the above API then the browser throws the following CORS blocked exception

```
No 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private AuthEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

    public WebSecurityConfig(AuthEntryPoint authEntryPoint){
        this.authEntryPoint=authEntryPoint;
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/contact").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/forget/**").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/user/register","/api/user/login").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/contact")
        .antMatchers("/api/forget/**")
                .antMatchers("/api/user/register","/api/user/login");
    }

}
```

**CrossConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class CrossConfig {

     @Bean
     public WebMvcConfigurer crossConfigurer(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
              registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE","OPTIONS")
                      .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
     }
}
```

**ResourceServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecurityProperties.class)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
      /............./
}
```

**Controller**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*",maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class VoyageUserController {

    private VoyageUserService voyageUserService;

    public VoyageUserController(VoyageUserService voyageUserService){
        this.voyageUserService=voyageUserService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}",produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_MODERATOR','ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<VoyageUserResponse> getUser(@PathVariable("id") String email){
          return (email.trim().isEmpty()) ?
                  new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) :
                  new ResponseEntity<>(voyageUserService.findVoyageUser(email),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**API Request From React using Axios**

```
if(email){
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:9090/api/user/${email}`,{
        headers:{
     'Authorization':'bearer '+token}
    })
    .then(res=>{
        const userDetail = res.data;
        console.log(userDetail);
       this.setState({
           voyageUser:userDetail
       });
      this.setIsLogged(true);
    }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error);
        this.setIsLogged(false);
    });
   }
```

I have done all things which are available in **StackOverflow as answers**, But still, the browser throws CORS blocked exception.

**Note** - There are no syntax errors in my code, if the question contains something,just ignore.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** - The problem is identified as The `ResourceServerConfig` class is loading before `WebSecurityConfig` class that is the cause for `CORS` error, So i decided to do authorization configuration in `ResourceServerConfig` class.

**ResourceServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecurityProperties.class)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

 @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/contact").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/forget/**").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/user/register","/api/user/login").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }


    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

It works with browsers without `CORS` error